# Is it allowed comparing the pointers on static class fields in static_assert?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-assert

I was trying to verify in a `static_assert` that a program had really two distinct classes produced from a template by comparing the pointers on their static fields. After some simplifications the program looks as follows:

```
template<int N> struct C { 
    static int x; 
};

template<int N> int C<N>::x = 0;

int main() { 
    static_assert(&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x); 
}
```

Clang is ok with it, but GCC prints the error:

```
error: non-constant condition for static assertion
```

demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o6dE3GaMK

I wonder whether this type of check is really allowed to do in compile time?

Comment: `that a program had really two distinct classes produced from a template` why do you need to know this? From the perspective of your code `C<0>` and `C<1>` are distinct types, why is it important for you if those share memory in the binary representation?

Comment: I agree that initial intention can be more easily fulfilled with `!std::is_same_v`. But now it is more interesting to find the answer on the question about address comparison.

Comment: I'm stuck on the definition of the static member variable. How many of them are defined? As many as there are templates that are actually used?

Comment: @Fedor, As for the condition, if accepted by the compiler, will always be `true` since C<0> and C<1> are different types in connection with the fact that making these variables share the same memory, under the `as-if` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule, is not permitted since a compiler cannot know whether or not and how the objects of these variables are accessed from other translation units. As for the compilation issue, some details are in my answer post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile-time equality comparison of the pointers on static class members is allowed.

The problem with original code was only in GCC and due to [old GCC bug 85428](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85428).

To workaround it, one can explicitly instantiate the templates as follows:

```
template<int N> struct C { 
    static int x; 
};

template<int N> int C<N>::x = 0;

template struct C<0>;
template struct C<1>;

int main() { 
    static_assert(&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x); 
}
```

This program is now accepted by all 3 major compilers, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Kss3x8GnW

Answer (score 1):

This should be more comment than an answer, but it does not fit in a readable way in the comments section.

So regarding the intent of the question:

> I was trying to verify in a `static_assert` that a program had really two distinct classes produced from a template by comparing the pointers on their static fields

Your code snippet is a template for a class:

```
template<int N> struct C { 
    static int x; 
};
```

This means that it is not a class by itself but a blueprint. The actual classes are `C<0>` and `C<1>`. If the values chosen for `N` are distinct then the resulting classes are distinct.

To figure out if two types are distinct you would use (as you correctly mention in your comment) `std::is_same_v`:

```
static_assert( !std::is_same_v<C<0>,C<1>>);
```

No matter if `static_assert(&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x);` is valid or not you shouldn't use it to figure out if those types are distinct from the perspective of the language. In the worst case you would - due to requesting the memory address of a member - prevent the compiler to do some optimizations it could before.

---

Now you could say the compiler can do optimizations based on the [as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) and share parts between those types, so they are not distinct on the binary level (distinct on the language and distinct in the binary are two different things).

But to which degree those are distinct on the binary level cannot be really tested within the code due to the same [as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rules.

Let's assume for a moment that `static_assert(&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x);` would work, then `&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x` has to evaluate to `true`, because the `C<0>` and `C<1>` are distinct type. This could happen due to two things:

1. Because you ask for the memory address of `x` for `C<0>` and `C<1>` you actually prevent the compiler to do an optimization after which they would share `x` on the binary level, so the memory address on the binary level is actually different.
2. The compiler still does the optimization so that `x` is shared between `C<0>` and `C<1>`.  But the outcome of `&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x` would still be `true` because it has to be `true` according to the [as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule. So even if the address of `x` for both distinct types `C<0>` and `C<1>` would be the same on the binary level the `static_assert` test would be `true`.

Comment: Whether or not an implimentation stores `C<0>::x` and `C<1>::x` at the same address (or not stores at all), `&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x` must evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Asboslutely correct. I for some reason had `static_assert(&C<0>::x == &C<1>::x)` in mind when writing `false`, I corrected that. The rest of the text was written according to `&C<0>::x` must never be equal to `&C<1>::x`

Comment: I'm not sure reference to the as-if rule is correct since it affects the **behavior**, not whether a program is ill-formed.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I was not talking about whether the code is ill-formed or not. From the perspective of the language `C<0>` and `C<1>` are distinct types (see first part - but I will make that clearer). If the question is about if they are distinct on the binary level or if those are actually the same type from the perspective of the resulting binary, a test using memory addresses does not make sense to due the as-if rule, or due to the fact that observing it changes the outcome.

Comment: @ArthurP.Golubev If the `&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x` is done at runtime (or when `&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x` doing at compile time is valid) then this test has to return `true` because those are distinct types. From the perspective of the c++ code, this test is done on the actual memory address. But the compiler could - based on the "as-if" rule completely optimize the existence of the `x` in memory away if there is no observed difference. But the test still needs to be `true` even if `x` does not exist in memory in the actual binary.

Comment: @ArthurP.Golubev So the `&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x` done in the code doesn't say anything about the existence of the memory address at all. The compiled binary behaves "as-if" the memory address actually exists, but it does not need to exist. (See this slightly modified code on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8YKWP4b6x), I changed it to only do a runtime test to avoid the discussion if the `static_assert` is valid, and made `x` `const` to force the compiler to optimize the `x` away from memory, so the value of x only exists as part of the instructions)

Comment: @t.niese, Making these variables share the same memory, under the `as-if` rule, is not permitted since a compiler cannot know whether or not and how the objects of these variables are accessed from other translation units.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, comparison of pointers to static class members (including for classes generated in result of template instantiations) in a `static_assert` clause is allowed, and pointers to different objects (and the members of the different template instantiations are different objects) must compare unequal** (but one should understand that it has to do with comparing neither real run-time addresses nor even static addresses in an executable, if any in the executable (there are details of it below)).

Issuing the compilation error from the question is a result of a bug of `gcc`.

The bug report for the exact compilation error by the author of the question: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102175

The related bugs reports:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85428
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89074
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94716

The code will work for `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20` and `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17` if the fields are explicitly specialized, like as follows:

```
template<int N> struct C { 
    static int x; 
};

template<int N> int C<N>::x = 0;

template<> int C<0>::x = 0;
template<> int C<1>::x = 0;

int main() { 
    static_assert(&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x); 
}
```

---

As for specifically how it must be, according to the C++ standard (the following links are for the C++20 (the currently latest accepted version of the language) first post-publication draft, N4868):

- "*A specialization of a static data member template is a static data member.*" (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem#general-note-1);
- "*A static data member is not part of the subobjects of a class.*" (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.static#data-1);
- "*A pointer to member shall not point to a static member of a class*" (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.mptr#3);
- "*The type “pointer to member” is distinct from the type “pointer”*" (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.mptr#4);
- Pointers to different objects (and the members of the template specializations are different objects) compare unequal (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.eq#3);
- Nothing prevents comparison of pointers to objects with static storage duration from being constant expression, so it is allowed in a `static_assert` clause (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const);
- "*Constant expressions can be evaluated during translation.*" (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#note-1)

---

---

The following is in regards to the details of the fact that the usage of pointers at compile-time has nothing to do with using real objects addresses.

In C++, though during translation a pointer to an object with static storage duration can be compared with another such pointer, as well as with `nullptr`/`0` and with itself, it has nothing to do with using real addresses of the objects in memory while an execution, and the feature is just a stub, which utilizes the fact that every such object (even empty) has its own unique, non-null address and knowledge about life-time of the object.

The fact that the storage for the object with `static storage duration` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends makes addresses of such objects permanent during an execution of a program, and one may be misled that it makes such objects get their addresses at compile time, but it is not so.

Though in binary executables for most popular at present operating systems, addresses of variables with static storage duration are static, actually both:

- it is only a variant of implementation and is not guaranteed (C++ concerns only of the addresses being permanent within an execution);
- as C++ translation really works in practice for all implementations I ever heard about, translation units are compiled independently (some of the variables from other translation units just may not be known), so the static addresses are possible to be assigned only at linking stage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)), which is after compilation has been completed.

But though the standard factually:

- does not operate compiling and linking but only `translation`;
- does not consider that a variable intended to be allocated (defined) in another translation unit can really be not allocated (defined)

when compiling in any case, nevertheless:

- it is known whether or not an object exists (has memory location) in the current translation unit;
- it is obvious that if the object with static storage duration exists, its address is not equal to `nullptr`/`0`;
- it is expected that a declared object is defined/allocated in any one translation unit.

So, the standard considers all such objects to have unique, not null addresses.

---

---

The following is in regards to the related cases in `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20` and `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17` in practice.

---

For static fields of a class (not template),

even if we declare them in the current translation unit but not define

```
class D {
public:
    static int d1;
    static int d2;
};
```

it is possible to compare an address with `nullptr`/`0`

```
static_assert(&D::d1 != nullptr);  // compiles successfully
static_assert(&D::d1 != 0);  // compiles successfully
```

One more time, the conditions have nothing to do with using the address of an object absolutely.
Even if we don’t define the static fields in any translation unit at all, the compiler checks the conditions with `true` result anyway, and only the linker will issue an `undefined reference` in case we try to `odr-use` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) the undefined object somewhere in the code.

Exactly the same is for comparing an address of a static field with itself

```
static_assert(&D::d1 == &D::d1); // compiles successfully
```

Note, the relation comparing with `nullptr`/`0`

```
static_assert(&D::d1 > nullptr);  // compiles successfully with `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17` but NOT with `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20`
static_assert(&D::d1 > 0);  // compiles successfully with `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17` but NOT with `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20`
```

successfully compiles with `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17`, but not with `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20`, and it respectively corresponds to `C++17`, which for the cases says "*neither pointer compares greater than the other*" (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.rel#3.3), for `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17`, and `C++20`, which for the case says "*neither pointer is required to compare greater than the other*" (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.rel#4.3), for `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20`, language versions.

---

**For a compile-time condition for comparing addresses of different objects it differs**.

If the variables are not defined in the current translation unit (even if they are in another one), the compiler doesn't accept the condition as a valid `constant expression`.

```
static_assert(&D::d1 != &D::d2); // error: ‘((& D::d1) != (& D::d2))’ is not a constant expression
```

Note, though it make sense from the point of view that the compiler does not know whether or not the object was really defined (allocated) in any one of the other translation units, **it violates the standard**, **which does not require the pointers point to defined objects for the comparing**;

if they are defined in the current translation unit, the condition is compiled successfully.

```
class D {
public:
    static int d1;
    static int d2;
};

int D::d1 = 0;
int D::d2 = 0;

static_assert(&D::d1 == &D::d1); // compiles successfully
```

---

As for templates,

if we try to compare addresses of the objects of specializations of the class template themselves, the result (except as in the note right below) is the same as for the specializations of the static fields of the class template from the question.

Note,  according to the standard, `reinterpret_cast` prevents an expression from being a `constant expression` (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.15), so `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20`, as well as `clang 13.0.0 with -std=c++20` and `msvc v19.29 VS16.11 with /std:c++17` , refuses to compile `reinterpret_cast` in the `constant expression`, but `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17` does accept it, so lets try to compare the addresses in a `static_assert` clause with `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17`.

So, for the following code for `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17`

```
template<int N> struct C { 
    static int x; 
};

template<int N> C<N> cI;

static_assert(reinterpret_cast<const void *>(&cI<0>) != reinterpret_cast<const void *>(&cI<1>)); //error: ‘(((const void*)(& cI<0>)) != ((const void*)(& cI<1>)))’ is not a constant expression
```

comparing addresses clause is not accepted by the compiler,

but if the template is explicitly specialized

```
C<0> c0;
C<1> c1;
```

we can compare the addresses at compile-time (for `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17`)

```
static_assert(reinterpret_cast<const void *>(&c0) != reinterpret_cast<const void *>(&c1)); //successfully compiled
```

It should be noted that

```
template<> int C<0>::x = 0;
template<> int C<1>::x = 0;
```

from the first code block of the answer and

```
C<0> c0;
C<1> c1;
```

are definitions of the variables, which create objects in the same translation unit.

And does

```
template<int N> int C<N>::x = 0;
```

and

```
template<int N> C<N> cI;
```

factually do the same with `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20` and `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17`?

The check is as follows. If I involve an additional source file with creation of the objects by template specializations as follows

```
template<int N> struct C { 
    static int x; 
};

template<> int C<0>::x = 0;
template<> int C<1>::x = 0;
```

and keep in the `main.cpp` the definition of a non-template data member of a class template and induce implicit instantiation as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N> struct C { 
    static int x; 
};

template<int N> int C<N>::x = 0;

int main() {
    std::cout << &C<0>::x << &C<1>::x << "\n";
}
```

I get

> multiple definition of `C<0>::x'
>
> multiple definition of `C<1>::x'

linker errors,

which means the objects are really created from `template<int N> int C<N>::x = 0;` too.

If I remove definitions from the additional file, all this compiles successfully and I can see the addresses in the run-time output.

But if I add

```
static_assert(&C<0>::x != &C<1>::x); // error: '((& C<0>::x) != (& C<1>::x))' is not a constant expression
```

after

```
std::cout << &C<0>::x << &C<1>::x << "\n";
```

it still is not accepted (though the objects are guaranteedly exist).

So, when we use

```
template<int N> int C<N>::x = 0;
```

the variables are factually created but their addresses are not comparable at compile time (for `gcc 11.2 with -std=c++20` and `gcc 7.5 with -std=c++17`).

---

Will wait for a response to the bug report https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102175 submitted by the author of the question.

Comment: The addresses of objects with static stotrage duration are usable in constant expressions in the abstract machine. And implementations must respect that. The naive notion of "compile time" vs "run time" is not an explanation in this context.

Comment: Your code is very similar to the original one, and since GCC starts accepting it, it looks as some bug in GCC

Comment: @Fedor Whether a compiler accepts some code or not does not say if it is valid or not. This can only be answered by consulting the specs and quoting that part. Which is not always easy. There is a chance that the part of the specs would say that it isn't valid but that there is no diagnostic required. But from reading the specs I'm not entirely sure whether it should be valid or not (I tend to say it is valid).  And sometimes the specs are not fully unambiguous resulting in one compiler accepting code and one not accepting code.

Comment: @Fedor You could check if there is an issue regarding that on the issue tracker on GCC and if not open an Issue there to let the people there discuss that.  Then you either know that it is a bug and it will be fixed or you know that they think that they are right and it might be a bug in clang, or an ambiguity in the specs .

Comment: @t.niese, good idea, I submitted GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102175

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, You are right, but these addresses have nothing to do with real run-time addresses, or even static addresses in the executable, if any, in an executable. I provided details in my answer post.